# Who is talking vs who are talking

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

I know we generally use the singular verb in this structure, even if the answer is plural (in AmE, I think). As in:

> Who is talking? - Jack is talking
>   Who is talking? - Joey and Sam are
>   talking.

What if I use **each other** at the end?

Who is/are talking to each other?

The plural form sounds natural, but I'd like to know what native speakers of English think, and how they use it.
There are other links discussing the same topic, but I am emphasizing on the phrase **to each other**.
And I know you can simply say "Who is talking?", but my question is what happens when you use 'to each other'?
Or is it that it is grammatically wrong yo use **to each other** at the end of this questiom?

Comment: I'm not native but I'd say, "**Who's talking to each other**" although it's rather odd.

Comment: @SovereignSun yes, 'each other' is odd. More likely to be 'who's talking to who?'

Comment: @marcellothearcane Yeh, or simply, "**Who's talking**" can include 1 to endless amount of speakers.

Comment: @SovereignSun that does have a sarcastic meaning sometimes, eg 'look who's talking!' when somebody is being hypocritical.

Comment: @marcellothearcane That's another side of "**Who's talkin'**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the plural in "who are" or "what are", you are expressing your expectation about the answer.  You would not ask "Who are picking me up?" unless for some reason, it seemed likely or certain the task would be undertaken by two or more people.

No literate English speaker would say, "Who is the top five tennis players in the world?"  *Players* takes *are*.  So you would say (ignoring the somewhat clumsy construction) "Who are the two people who are talking to each other?"

Therefore, it's correct to ask "Who are talking to each other?"

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when you ask "Who is talking?" it means that you don't know the number of persons. Maybe you heard only one person's voice.  When you hear two or more than two people, then you know that there is more than one person talking.

Then, you should use "Who are talking?" Or "Who are talking to each other?".